# read only non-merged files in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, merge, delta-lake

I have N deltas in N folders (ex. /user/deltas/1/delta1.csv, /user/deltas/2/delta2csv,.../user/deltas/n/deltaN.csv)
all deltas have same columns, only information in columns is different.

i have a code for reading my csv files from folder "deltas"

```
dfTable = spark.read.format("csv").option("recursiveFileLookup","true")\
.option("header", "true).load("/home/user/deltas/")
```

and i gonna use deltaTable.merge to merge and update information from deltas and write updated information in table (main_table.csv)
For example tommorow i will have new delta with another updated information, and i will run my code again to refresh data in my main_table.csv .
How to avoid deltas that have already been used by deltaTable.merge earlier to the file main_table.csv ?
is it possible maybe to change file type after delta's run for example to parquet and thats how to avoid re-using deltas again? because im reading csv files, not parquet, or something like log files etc..

Answer (score 0):

I think a [time path filter](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/sql-data-sources-generic-options.html#modification-time-path-filters) might work well for your use case. If you are running your code daily (either manually or with a job), then you could use the `modifiedAfter` parameter to only load files that were modified after 1 day ago (or however often you are rerunning this code).

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

timestamp_last_run = (datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%Y-%m-%dT-%H:%M:%S")

dfTable = spark.read.format("csv").option("recursiveFileLookup","true")\
.option("header", "true).load("/home/user/deltas/", modifiedAfter=timestamp_last_run)

## ...perform merge operation and save data in main_table.csv
```

Comment: thank you, should i delete in code "-timedelta(days=1)" if i want to run the code immidiatly right after the execution?

Comment: @nox8315 there needs to be some `timedelta` because we are using the `modifiedAfter` parameter. for example, if a bunch of new deltas were saved in `/home/user/deltas/` 5 minutes ago, and you use `modifiedAfter=datetime.now()`, nothing will be loaded because there are no deltas that were modified after the current datetime. But if you use `modifiedAfter=datetime.now() - timedelta(minutes=10)`, then you would correctly load the most recent deltas